# Intel Ethernet I219-LM Driver in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, ethernet

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Desktop, but Ethernet is not connected.
My Computer uses Intel Ethernet Connection I219-LM.
In my opnion, Ubuntu doesn't have installed a proposal network driver. I can't find ethernet driver.

Comment: The driver for your device is *e1000e*. Does it load without error? `sudo modprobe e1000e` Is there any clue in the log? `dmesg | grep e1000e` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I’m having the same issue. The i219 isn’t being detected. When I run those commands the e1000e driver loads and there are no errors.

Answer (score 7):

Same ethernet adaptor for me on my ubuntu 16.

This worked:

- Download [e1000e-3.4.2.1](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-) (Check latest on Intel website).
- Got the tar.gz file downloaded untar it:

  ```
  tar xfv e1000e-3.4.2.1.tar.gz
  ```
- Goto src directory

  ```
  cd src
  ```
- Compile and install

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```
- Reboot

This worked for me.

Comment: And for me too in Debian9 . Thanks!

Comment: This appears to have worked for me, too.  Ubuntu 20.04, Thinkpad T460s w/ i219-LM.  After compiling the new driver and rebooting it's been hours since I've seen my wired internet drop.  Fingers crossed for more hours to come. Note: The version I downloaded was e1000e 3.8.4, which apparently was written in 2019. I'm guessing this will be the final version.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same case that I can't see the network card on my Linux only computer which uses *Intel Ethernet card*. And installing the Intel driver didn't help. There's another topic about an "Wired Unmanaged" Ethernet card, that Lou Burnard suggested to:

1. Edit the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`and change the line `managed=false` to `managed=true`
2. Restart network manager with `sudo service network-manager restart`.
   And for me I need to wait for it to work.

Comment: First time I've touched that file and it says managed=false already, but I did install a bridge with bridge-utils for KVM, so that might have changed it without my knowing.

Answer (score 0):

**tldr; switch to [HWE kernels](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) which provide drivers/firmwares for newer devices**

Ran into this issue with a new Lenovo P350 Tiny. These machines contain the same I219-LM Ethernet card that is not detected in *Ubuntu 20.04 LTS*.

*Ubuntu 20.04 LTS* does contain the *Intel e1000e* kernel drivers, except they're an older version **3.2.6-k**, circa *2015!* Brings a whole new definition to *stability* =)

Anyway, I believe all the answers above will work - compiling from scratch, etc, but the easiest solution for me was to use the [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) kernels:

```
apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
```

*Obviously, for this to work, an offline apt package repository or another mechanism to install HWE kernel packages.*

And reboot into the new HWE kernel.