# Ubuntu 18.04 - No longer access wired Internet through ethernet after Kernel upgrade and supsended laptop

Tags: network-manager, ethernet, wired

I am using Trisquel 9 (based off of Ubuntu 18.04 -- Bionic) with KDE Plasma.

I recently upgraded the libre Linux Kernel to 5.11.4-gnu which required many system services to be restarted. After the computer restarted, I began working again just fine with my wired Internet connection. After a while of no activity, the system suspended itself. When I attempted to re-use the Internet again I could not get it work.

The Network Manager applet is a red color. It lists the Active connections. Although I am connected and the Ethernet cable is plugged in, I am not able to access the Internet.

Following various Internet posts about not being able to connect to a wired network, I rebooted the computer to an older Kernel version (5.9.2-gnu) to see if that would solve the issue & it did not either.

Below is the result of issuing the following command in Konsole:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: ec:21:e5:0f:3e:1f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.9.2-gnu firmware=0.13-
```

Below is the result of issuing the following command in Konsole:

```
$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service

● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-03-17 10:59:03 CDT; 14min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 5359 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─5359 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4374] keyfile: add connection in-memory (c23e1caa-65dd-494c-8ca8-8a88dc74127c,"enp0s31f6")
Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4404] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4450] device (enp0s31f6): Activation: starting connection 'enp0s31f6' (c23e1caa-65dd-494c-8ca8-8a88dc74127c)
Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4744] device (enp0s31f6): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4750] device (enp0s31f6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4753] device (enp0s31f6): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4754] device (enp0s31f6): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4757] device (enp0s31f6): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4759] device (enp0s31f6): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 17 11:04:09 nvsu NetworkManager[5359]: <info>  [1615997049.4788] device (enp0s31f6): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

What should I do to get my wired Internet connection working again?

Thank you.

Comment: It may be based on Ubuntu I do not see that on their web site. It is not Ubuntu so sorry no support here for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, "based on" isn't close enough. We do not keep track of the changes that other distros make, so we do not answer questions about them. We are happy to help folks who [encounter this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067564/intel-ethernet-i219-lm-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04) on a stock install of a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: This Web page describes how Trisquel GNU/Linux is created: https://trisquel.info/en/wiki/how-trisquel-made. Since Version 2.0, it is based off of Ubuntu. I will post this question on Stack Overflow. Thank you.